# Why am I getting the error message: "restrict" not allowed?

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, cuda, restrict-qualifier

I'm writing a CUDA kernel and want to `__restrict__` some of my parameters. I'm getting the error message:

> `"restrict" is not allowed`

Is it not allowed for some variable types? For some combinations of parameters? Because of some compiler flags? Because I've been naughty?

Simplified kernel signature:

```
template <typename T> foo(
    const T a[],
    __restrict__ SomeType b[],
    const T c
) {
    /* etc. */
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use `__restrict__` on a pointer type. That is also the only context in which `__restrict__` makes sense.

Comment: Just to amplify: `__restrict__ SomeType b[]` is not OK.  `SomeType __restrict__ b[]` is not OK.  `__restrict__ SomeType *b` is not OK.  `SomeType* __restrict__ b` is OK.  Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#restrict) for an example.

Comment: So, you're saying that if I want a 'restrict'ed pointer to SomeType, there's no way I can use square bracket notation for the parameter?

Comment: @einpoklum: You can't modify the value of the array reference (I'm not sure if that is the correct terminology). That is, you can't perform any pointer arithmetic on `b` and it will always point to the same point in memory. Which is why the aliasing issue does not apply to `b`. You can make a pointer by taking the address of `b`. You can use `__restrict__` on that new pointer.

Comment: @einpoklum: I just realized that you can get aliasing issues if you use multiple indexes into the same array, so I'm not sure now why `__restrict__` can't be applied to an array. Maybe the compiler already assumes no aliasing for arrays. Would have to research...

Comment: I know that in C, `void foo(int a[])` is define to be exactly `void foo(int* a)`; that is, you can't pass arrays anyway, only pointers. Isn't that also the case in C++?

Comment: @einpoklum: Yes, it is the case -- you can't pass arrays in C++ either. Arrays are implicitly converted to pointers. But arrays and pointers have different semantics. See for instance, http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers_vs_arrays.htm.

Comment: I know very well about the differences. The point is, if you can't pass arrays, how can `T* __restrict__ ptr`  be Ok while `T __restrict__ ptr[]` not be Ok?

Comment: @einpoklum: I fail to see how those two are related...? Let's move to chat if you want to clarify. But, as I mentioned, I can see a use case for `__restrict__` on arrays unless the compiler assumes that there is no aliasing for arrays. Beyond that, I would have to research.

Comment: A [formal definition](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/restrict.html#formal-definition) of `restrict` is given in the c99 standard (especially note the linked section 3.10).  `restrict` is a *pointer qualifier*.  It does not qualify the object pointed to.  Therefore, at the moment `restrict` is encountered, we must be referring to a *pointer type*.  The cuda `__restrict__` qualifier mimics this behavior. So if `T` is not a pointer type, then `T restrict` will not work, regardless of what follows it.  You cannot do what you are suggesting in C, either.  This is not really a CUDA issue.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Got it. Ok then.

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen if you used `__restrict__` on a pointer parameter to a function, but got the order wrong, e.g.:

```
__device__ int bar(float __restrict__ *  x); // wrong order!
```

instead of:

```
__device__ int bar(float * __restrict__ x); // correct order
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more in detail:
Did you show a correct order or an example of a wrong one?
Can you write one example of a correct one and one example of a wrong one and explain why the wrong one is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @ElectRocnic: You're quite right, see edit.